# How to force a true Git merge so a line is drawn from a branch to master even when files are the same?

Tags: git, merge

I did a merge from branch xyz to master involving about 20 files, and there were no conflicts.  I cannot remember the options I used unfortunately, but whatever I did, the resulting code is the desired code **but no line was drawn from branch xyz to master**.  I want the line from xyz to master so that people can clearly see from the commit graph that the merge happened.  Instead of a line from branch xyz to master I have a new node on master as if I created/edit these files on the master branch without them coming from branch xyz.

I have attempted to do the merge again using the 'correct' options that cause the line to be drawn from xyz to master, but Git is now telling me that everything is "Already up to date" which is technically true.  In other SCM tools, I've been able to force a merge (even if the files were the same) and/or draw a line from one branch to another.

What are some of the best Git techniques for adding merge lines when the files between two branches are the same?  Or best ideas for a second attempt on this?

**UPDATE: Unfortunately, I have pushed my changes to a central repo that my fellow developers pull from, so doing a hard reset suggest by 'tbekolay' will unlikely solve my problem.**

Answer (score 4):

The merge option that you're looking for is `--no-ff` (see [git merge man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)).

The merge that you did previously resolved as a fast-forward merge, meaning that it just took your branch and pasted it on top of master with no merge commit. Since you want the history of the branch existing, you want to explicitly include that merge commit. To do that, instead of

```
git merge xyz
```

you would do

```
git merge xyz --no-ff
```

which would give you the behavior you're wanting.

### If you haven't pushed yet

If you haven't pushed your changes to anyone else, then you can fix this cleanly by hard resetting master to its state before the merge, and then doing the merge with `--no-ff`.

To do that, assuming you haven't deleted branch `xyz` yet, first find the last commit before the merge with

```
git log
```

copy its hash, and then do

```
git reset --hard <commit_hash>
```

and then finally

```
git merge xyz --no--ff
```

### If you've already pushed

If you've already pushed but are very adamant in recovering the history that `xyz` was merged in, you can still achieve this, but the solution is not very clean, and it might be easier to live with the fast-forwarded merge.

But, if you want to do it, again fine the last commit before the merge with

```
git log
```

copy its hash, then do

```
git revert <commit_hash>..master
```

This will make a commit for each commit in the branch that just reverses that commit. This is kind of ugly; you can make it slightly less ugly by squashing all of those commits into a single reversing commit with

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

assuming that you haven't snuck a `git push` in between these steps. This will bring up an editor in which you can `pick` the first commit, and `squash` all of the other commits into that first commit. You may want to edit the commit message at the end to say something like `Reverting fast-forward merge of xyz`.

Your repository is now at the state it was before the fast-forward merge, kind of. It has the history of the merge, and you reverting that merge. At this point, you can

```
git merge xyz --no-ff
```

and you'll get a merge commit. Ironically, since `master` has changed a fair bit, you will now get a non-fast-forward merge even if you don't use `--no-ff`, but since that's the workflow you prefer, you might as well get in the habit of always merging with `--no-ff`.

Comment: I have already pushed to the central repo unfortunately.  What would be the solution if I have already pushed to the central repo?  Thanks for explaining the "no-ff" option however.

Comment: I added a section to my answer of one possible way to do it without rewriting history (since you should avoid rewriting history if anyone other than you might use this repository -- if it's a personal project noone else is using, you can do the hard reset, and force push, as Johnny Z mentions in his answer).

Comment: Your 'already pushed' solution is probably my best bet.  In my case, the xyz branch is designed to be a permanent branch that represents a build delivered to customers during a certain month so we can't delete it.  Personally, I think Git should offer a 'force merge' feature like other SCM tools for my scenario.  Thanks for your time tbekolay.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering from these changes already pushed to the server will be hard. You can follow tbekolay's steps to hard reset then do a `push -f` to your central repository. But, you would be rewriting history, and I do not recommend it. It will screw up your other developers.

I recommend dealing with a fast-forward merge this time, and making sure you are going `--no-ff` in the future.